# How to use placeholder '?' in LIKE operator?

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a Java-based desktop application with MySQL as my back end. In this application there is section called 'Search' where four fields are there - Key Skills (text field), Experience (combo box), City (combo box) and Notice Period (combo box). All the four field's value will be provided at run time. The key skills are comma separated values. I want a MySQL query using LIKE operator, with the help of which I don't have to provide comma separated values every time in the Key Skills text field. I just provide one value at run time and based on that value the query will fetch me the results using LIKE operator. My query is shown below

I have used placeholder '?' since my query is dynamic type. Is it possible to use placeholder in LIKE operator or does it only work with static type query?

```
String query = "SELECT F_Name, L_Name, Experience, Key_Skills, 
       FROM Candidate cd 
     JOIN Candidate2 cd2 ON(cd.Mobile = cd2.C_Mobile) 
      WHERE Key_Skills LIKE '%?%'";
```

When I executed the above query it produced an error stating - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Candidate cd JOIN Candidate2 cd2 ON(cd.Mobile = cd2.C_Mobile) WHERE Key_Skills' at line 1

Comment: Are you using JDBC to talk to your MySQL database or are you going via an ORM such as Hibernate?

Comment: I am using JDBC to communicate with MySQL

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
String query = 
  "SELECT F_Name, L_Name, Experience, Key_Skills " + 
  "FROM Candidate cd JOIN Candidate2 cd2 ON (cd.Mobile = cd2.C_Mobile) " + 
  "WHERE Key_Skills LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')";
```

When you execute the above code by passing a parameter say `'someskill'` the function `concat()` will produce this string `'%someskill%'` and the column `Key_Skills` will be compared to this concatenated string.

Answer (score 2):

Using concat you can build the `like` string in a simple way for managing param value:

```
   String query = "SELECT F_Name, L_Name, Experience, Key_Skills
     FROM Candidate cd 
     JOIN Candidate2 cd2 ON(cd.Mobile = cd2.C_Mobile) 
     WHERE Key_Skills LIKE concat('%' , ?, '%')";
```

NB you have a wrong comma in `key_Skills, FROM` - you must remove it.

It could be you have ambiguous column so I have updated the answer with a fully-qualified syntax.

```
  String query = "SELECT 
        cd.F_Name
      , cd.L_Name
      , cd.Experience
      , cd.Key_Skills
     FROM Candidate cd 
     INNER JOIN Candidate2 cd2 ON cd.Mobile = cd2.C_Mobile 
     WHERE cd.Key_Skills LIKE concat('%' , ?, '%')";
```

Comment: I tried this query before posting question here. It still didn't work. It showed me the same error which I have posted in my question.

Comment: @MayukhMitra  . in my answer  clearly there is a suggestion for remove the comma before FROM .. do it

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, '%')' at line 1. This is the error I got after removing the comma before FROM.

Comment: @MayukhMitra  answer updated .. with also a fully qualified  version.. anyway are you sure your query have proper single quote just aroud  % and the param string don't contain quote??  and be also sure for proper sequence of double and single quote

Answer (score 2):

You can do the prefix and suffix in the Java code instead of concatenating them in SQL.

```
WHERE Key_Skills LIKE ?";
```

Maybe even allowing wild cards:

```
keySkills = keySkills.replace('*', '%');
keySkills = keySkills.replace('?', '_');

preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + keySkills + "%");
```

The JDBC code will replace `?` with a prepared statement value, coerced
to the expected SQL string type. And `setString` takes care of escaping apostrophes and others.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Joop Eggen. Your code preparedStatement.setString( ) worked properly. I just replaced keySkills with text field ID and it worked perfectly.